# Cardinality of an infinite set

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

What is the cardinality of the set $B=\{ t: t \text{ solves some linear polynomial } mx+n=0, \text{ where } m,n\in\mathbb{Q}\}$.

Here is my thinking, please correct where my logic is flawed.

Since $x = \frac{-n}{m}$ solves the linear equation and we know that $m,n \in \mathbb{Q}$ then $x \in \mathbb{Q}$.  So $t$ is the set of ordered pairs on the given line in which it's coordinates are rational numbers.

Since the rationals have a cardinality of $\aleph_0$, then so does the set $B$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!!!

Comment: @EricWofsey Not sure if thats a typo.  This is how the problem was presented to me on homework.  Does seem kind of weird that there are no $t$'s in such equations

Comment: I've rewritten my answer since I didn't read what you wrote carefully enough at first (what you wrote is more mistaken than I realized).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have a basic confusion about what the question is asking.  The set $B$ does NOT depend on two numbers $m$ and $n$ as parameters.  Rather, $B$ is the set of all (presumably real) numbers $t$ such that there *exist* rational numbers $m$ and $n$ such that $mt+n=0$.

Also, even with $m$ and $n$ fixed, you seem to be confused about how to solve this equation.  The equation $mt+n=0$ only has one solution $t=\frac{-n}{m}$ (if $m\neq 0$), not a whole line's worth of solutions.  I'm not sure what you mean by "the given line".

However, the case $m=0$ is very important to this problem and you should not overlook it!  If $m=0$, for what values of $t$ does there exist a rational number $n$ such that $mt+n=0$?

Comment: if $m = 0$ then $x$ is undefined or n must equal zero ?

Comment: Right, but you're allowed to choose whatever $m$ and $n$ you want.

Comment: Well, if there is no $t$ that solves for $m=0,n\ne0$, then that's an empty set.  Right?

Comment: I think i misinterpreted the question.  Since the original question had $x$ in it, I took that to be an $x$-value of an ordered pair $t$.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: If $m=0$, for what values of $t$ does there exist a rational number $n$ such that $mt + n = 0$?  So for $m=0$ case $t$ can be anything but $n$ must also equal zero?

Comment: Right, $t$ can be anything.  It is true that $n$ "must" be $0$, but that's no problem since $0$ is rational.

Comment: So, since there is no restriction on $t$ for the $m=0$ case, can we say there is an uncountable amount of $t$'s that satisfy the equation?

Comment: Yep!  Do you know a more familiar name for the set $B$?

Comment: The real numbers? If so its cardinality is $\aleph_1$

Comment: It's the real numbers, but the cardinality of the real numbers is $2^{\aleph_0}$, not $\aleph_1$ (the usual axioms of set theory cannot prove whether or not $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$).